# Reactjs listen for state changes in app component

Tags: reactjs

I'm relatively new to React. I'm wanting to listen for state changes for a menu component I have. I need to have the state changes bubble up the highest level in the app, being the app.jsx itself. I have tried various methods in app to listen for events but none of them have worked so far. I'm not using redux in the app as it's just a menu that I'm opening and closing. How can I listen for this change throughout the app?

An assistance is appreciated.

!-- my component function

```
export default class Comp extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isOpen: false
    }

}

toggleDropdown = () => {
    const toggledIsOpen = this.state.isOpen ? false : true;

    this.setState({
        isOpen: toggledIsOpen
    });

}

render = () =>

    
  <button onClick={this.toggleDropdown}>Menu</button>
    
}
```

!--- app

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('//');
    console.log(this.state);
}

render = () =>

   <span> value of state to update here</span>
   <Comp/>

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with callback:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('//');
    console.log(this.state);
}
callBack(value) {
   console.log(value) // "testValue"
}
render = () => //note: you should have single component in return -> wrap this within div, for example

   <span> value of state to update here</span>
   <Comp cb={this.callBack}/>

 }


export default class Comp extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.toggleDropdown = this.toggleDropdown.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isOpen: false
    }

}

toggleDropdown = () => {
    const toggledIsOpen = this.state.isOpen ? false : true;

    this.setState({
        isOpen: toggledIsOpen
    });
    this.props.cb("testValue");

}

render = () =>


  <button onClick={this.toggleDropdown}>Menu</button>

}
```

Comment: Hi @andrew, I get the error: bundle.js:40741 Uncaught TypeError: _this.cb is not a function

Comment: @Jimi, of course, my mistake, there should be `this.props.cb`. I've edited.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **Lifting State Up** principle. This is used for sharing a state between two components. The most common operation is to move it up to their closest common ancestor.

Shared State: When we update a descendant's state, an other component (in your case - app) should reflect the change (and vice versa)

Read more: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html